# How do I install Iris on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, screen, backlight

I downloaded the 64-bit zip file but I've been unable to find the solution.

[The Iris website](https://iristech.co/)

[image]

That happens when I try the "extract here" option.

Regards

Comment: What's your specific issue? Have you extracted the .zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but without installing. I extracted and ran the iris.sh file in the folder which will start the program. It's like a AppImage, if your familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Just extract (right click > extract here) and run (doubleclick the extracted file)  it as described [here](https://iristech.co/how-to-install-iris-on-linux-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

Extract the zip file and then go to the directory it is in in the terminal and then, chmod +x . it should launch on clicking the icon.